# log4j not logging info level

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following in log4j.xml file, when I run my application. Only error logs are getting printed in console, info logs are not getting printed. But if I comment out jdbcAppender part and only use

I would like to have both error and info to printed and at the same time error logs needs to be inserted into database table errors.

How can I do this?

Regards

```
<appender name="jdbcAppender" class="bean.CustomJdbcAppender"> 
        <param name = "jndiDataSource" value="myjdbcDS"/>        
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
              value="INSERT INTO errors (log_level, location, message) VALUES ( '%p',
              '%C;%L', '%m' )" 
            /> 
        </layout> 
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
              value="%d{ISO8601} %p (%C;%L) %m%n" 
            /> 
        </layout> 
    </appender> 
    <category name="bean"><priority value="error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="jdbcAppender"/> 
    </category>
    <root> 
        <priority value="info"/> 
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> 
    </root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ERROR` priority from the logger `bean` such that its logging level is inherited from the root logger , which is set to the `INFO` level . Then any logging events coming from this logger which level is larger or equal to `INFO`  can be intercepted and forward to the `jdbcAppender` and `STDOUT` .

```
  <category name="bean">
    <appender-ref ref="jdbcAppender"/> 
  </category>
```

To restrict only the `ERROR` level events can be actually logged by `jdbcAppender` , apply and configure the `LevelMatchFilter` and `DenyAllFilter` on the `jdbcAppender`

```
<appender name="jdbcAppender" class="bean.CustomJdbcAppender"> 
        <param name = "jndiDataSource" value="myjdbcDS"/>        
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
           <param name="ConversionPattern" value="INSERT INTO errors (log_level, location, message) VALUES ( '%p','%C;%L', '%m' )"  /> 
        </layout> 
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
                  <param name="LevelToMatch" value="error" />
                  <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
        </filter>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" />
 </appender>
```